# How to edit UWP Control Templates in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, uwp-xaml

I'm building a UWP app targeting Fall Creators Update using VS/Blend 2017 15.6.2.  I can't edit control templates in the designer.  It's really frustrating.
When I right-click on a control in the Document Outline (or Objects and Timeline) window, then click "Edit Template", the "Edit Current" option is always disabled.
Does anybody know...is this just not supported anymore (which would really suck) or am I doing something wrong?  Am I missing an extension or something?  Anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that I am seeing this behavior as well. I have [reported this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/214590/cannot-edit-current-template-of-uwp-controls.html) to the Visual Studio Feedback but I suspect the reason is that the new Visual Studio XAML Designer does not yet support this scenario.